Heatmap- customizing autodesk heatmap colors?
I have created a heatmap using the demo https://aps-iot-extensions-demo.autodesk.io/ I'm trying to register surface shading
this._dataVizExt.registerSurfaceShadingColors('Temperature', [0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0xff0000]);
    this._dataVizExt.registerSurfaceShadingColors('Humidity', [0x0000ff, 0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0xff0000]);
    this._dataVizExt.registerSurfaceShadingColors('IAQ', [0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0xff0000]);
   

But it is using the default surface shading colors, I have attached the image for the reference
Heatmap viewer
Can anyone please guide how can I apply customer color in heatmap.

Two things:
When calling the dataVizExt.registerSurfaceShadingColors method, make sure the first argument is the ID of the channel, not its name. For example, for the mocked temperature data, it would be "temp", and not "Temperature".
Also, note that the color legend shown in the "Heatmaps" panel is not automatically synced with the heatmap colors in the viewer. You
will need to update the legend separately.
